# Is there a way to execute code in the command line prompt (PS1) without using backticks?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, prompt, command-substitution

I am using this piece of code directly in the command prompt (PS1), and it tells me whether the previous command executed correctly.

```
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e \"\e[1;32m[⚡️ ]\"\e[0m; else echo -e \"\e[1;31m[ ]\"\e[0m; fi\`-[\u@\h: \w]"
```

I don't like the backticks notation. Is there a way to execute it without using ``?

Also, is there a reason this would interfere with the results from a another script?  I've exposed a function that I called in the command prompt, but this piece messes up the results.  The function gets called only once when PS1 is exported and not every time that the command prompt is loaded.

Update 1:
So I tried the plain "$()" but it didn't work.  And, now I am more puzzled because if add a backslash to it works – "\$()".  Why is this?  Does anyone know of this?  Does "$" need to be escaped?

The original works:

```
export PS1="[\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e \"\e[1;32m[⚡️ ]\"\e[0m; else echo -e \"\e[1;31m[ ]\"\e[0m; fi\`]-[\u@\h: \w] \$ "
```

Result:

```
[⚡️ ]-[rordev@Luiss-MBP: ~/Development/test] $
```

This doesn't work:

```
export PS1="[$(if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo -e \e[1;32m[⚡️ ]\e[0m; else echo -e \e[1;31m[ ]\e[0m; fi)]-[\u@\h: \w] \$ "
```

Result:

```
-bash: 32m[⚡️: command not found
[e[1]-[rordev@Luiss-MBP: ~/Development/test] $
```

But this works. Why? and why is the backslash needed before`$()`?

```
export PS1="\$(if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e \"\e[1;32m[⚡️ ]\"\e[0m; else echo -e \"\e[1;31m[ ]\"\e[0m; fi)-[\u@\h: \w] \$ "
```

Result:

```
[⚡️ ]-[rordev@Luiss-MBP: ~/Development/test] $
```

Update 2:
I tried the suggestions and it works. Well, sort of.

I have to call the conditional first and the function last.

```
PS1="\$(if [ \$? = 0]; then ...; else ...; fi)-[\u@\h: \w\$(myFunction)]"
```

But it doesn't work the other way.

```
PS1="[\u@\h: \w\$(myFunction)]-\$(if [ \$? = 0]; then ...; else ...; fi)"
```

The function is called and the results are displayed, but the conditional does not seem to be executing, or rather the status code returned seems to always be 0.  So it always shows the first part of the conditional.

Any ideas about that?  I suspect that it has something to do with the order in which the command substitutions are executed.

Comment: `$()` is the preferred syntax over backticks

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't execute it.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then ... fi\`
> ```
>
> Update: So I tried the plain "$()" but it didn't work. And, now I am more puzzled because if add a forward slash to it works - "\$()".

The `\` is a backslash, not a forward slash.

You need to escape the `$` here for the same reason you escaped the backticks in the first snippet: because otherwise the command substitution is expanded *immediately*, when setting `PS1`, and not when `PS1` is used to produce a prompt.

You're better off using single quotes around the assignment, they'll prevent expanding variables and command substitutions for the whole string.

```
PS1='$(if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo -e "\[\e[1;31m\][boom]\[\e[0m\] "; fi)\u@\h \w\$ '
```

Note, that you need to wrap the escape codes within `\[ ... \]` to tell bash that they don't print, and that it shouldn't take them into account when calculating the width of the prompt (mentioned in passing in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)). (I don't know if Bash can correctly deal with the graphic characters you used, and I can't test.)

Comment: proper escape codes for ANSI colors do not need a closing square backet ]

Comment: @luis.madrigal, As terminal control sequences, no, they don't contain a `]`. To tell the shell the control sequence doesn't produce visible characters, yes, you do need the brackets, and yes you do need to close them. Read the last paragraph again.

Comment: Take 2:   A proper escape codes for ANSI colors does not need a closing square backet "]".  The open square bracket "[" is the only one needed and it is called the Control Sequence Introducer or CSI for short and tells the interpreter to accept the characters that follow as part of the escape sequence.  The m is the closing character in the sequence and it is called the final character.

Comment: @luis.madrigal, yes, I know. The control sequence `\e[1;31m` doesn't contain a closing bracket.

Comment: I didn't see your comment.  I was in the middle of  writing the my second comment. Thanks for the response it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't like the backticks notation, is there a way to execute it without using ``?

- Yes, alternative syntax for [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)  is to use the form **`$(...)`**, which has a couple of advantages according to the [Advanced Bash-scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

> The function is called and the results are displayed, but the conditional does not seem to be executing, or rather the status code returned seems to always be 0. So it always shows the first part of the conditional.
>
> Any ideas about that? I suspect that it has something to do with the order in which the command substitutions are executed.

- My suggestion is to transfer all the **logic** to the [**PROMPT_COMMAND**](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) variable to make things clear.
  As stated at the [Bash Prompt Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) *The contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command* ***just before*** *Bash displays a prompt*, which means, before the call to the `$PS1` variable.

For example:

```
    # Notice that we need to save the exit status to preserve it
    # and avoid what you are reporting(always returning 0)
    choose_icon() {
        RET=$?; # Save the exit status
        # Using short circuit evaluation to make statement shorter
        [[ $RET != 0 ]] && ISTATUS= || ISTATUS=⚡️
        return "$RET" # Return the original exit status to your shell
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="choose_icon" # or/and any other function/command
    PS1='[$ISTATUS]\u@\h \w\$ '
```

Comment: the command substitution runs in a subshell, and you don't need to `export` variables for them to be seen by one.

Comment: the idea of `RET=$?` && `return "${RET}"` helps me handle multiple funcs in `PS1`. thanks.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you move the assignment of `PS1='...'` _into_ the choose_icon function then it will get dynamically recalculated on each call. The way this answer has it laid out it will only get set once and not subsequently update.